# modifying map value of type slice in place

Tags: go

```
mp := map[string][]int{
"1" : {1,2,3,4},
}


for _,s := range mp {
  i:= 0
  for _,v:=range s{
    if v%2==0 {
      s[i] = v
      i++
    }
  }
  s = s[:i]
  // I tried mp[k] = s and it works fine
}

want := map[string][]int{
"1" : {2,4},
}

if !reflect.DeepEqual(mp,want) {
   fmt.Printf("not expected")
   fmt.Println(mp)
}
```

With the above code I'm not able to remove odd integers from the slice.

I changed this to

```
mp := map[string][]int{
"1" : {1,2,3,4},
}


for k,s := range mp {
  i:= 0
  for _,v:=range s{
    if v%2==0 {
      s[i] = v
      i++
    }
  }
  s = s[:i]
  mp[k] = s
}

want := map[string][]int{
"1" : {2,4},
}
```

And now it works.
I am wondering what is the problem with the first piece of code.
I think s's address is not changed.

Comment: The variables in a for-loop are copies.

Answer (score 2):

```
for k,s := range mp {
```

Here **s** keeps the value of **mp**, which is **[]int**.

If you change or modify the **s** in the loop it won't affect the value of **mp**, cause **s** is just a copy of the value of **mp**. If you want to affect the change into **mp** then modify with **mp[k]**.